# OpenLayers.Request.GET returns 0 in Status

Tags: openlayers

I have problem with this simple code:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Test OpenLayers.Request.GET</TITLE>
        <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function handler(request) {
                alert("Status: "+request.status+" StatusText: "+request.statusText);
            }

            OpenLayers.Request.GET({
                url: "http://www.google.com",
                callback: handler,
                success: handler
            });
        </script>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Alert always shows:

Status: 0 StatusText:

Please, help me.

Comment: I immediately get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error from your code. Could this be your problem?

Comment: How did you get this error?

Comment: By looking at the dev console in chrome.